# Runtime error when I run the program but not when i use debugger

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to make a c/c++ program where the program accepts a txt file with several words, one per line, and finds the edit distance(also called levenshtein distance) with a specific word.

I have a weird problem.

My code encounters a runtime error after a reading a couple of words when I run it in code-blocks.  It debugs fine when i use the code-blocks debugger.

I have been looking around and I found uninitialised variables can be a problem. But whenever i comment the line where i am calling the function `minDistance` `count[i]=minDistance(word,lines[i]);`, the code runs fine and prints out all the words in the file. So that's not a problem I guess.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Following is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;
static int minDistance(char* word1, char* word2)
{
    const int l1 = strlen(word1);
    const int l2 = strlen(word2);
    int i=0,j=0;
    int **d = new int*[l2 + 1];
    for(i=0;i<l1+1;++i)
        d[i]=new int[l1+1];

    // the edit distance between an empty string and the prefixes of
    // word2
    for (i = 0; i < l2 + 1; i++) {
        d[0][i] = i;
    }

    // the edit distance between an empty string and the prefixes of
    // word1
    for (j = 0; j < l1 + 1; j++) {
        d[j][0] = j;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < l1 + 1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < l2 + 1; j++) {
            if (word1[i - 1] == word2[j - 1]) {
                d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j - 1];
            } else {
                d[i][j] = min(min(1 + d[i][j - 1], 1 + d[i - 1][j]),
                1 + d[i - 1][j - 1]); // min of insertion,
                // deletion, replacement
            }
        }
    }

    return d[l1][l2];
}

void lines()
{
  int i=0;
  char * lines[10];
  int count[10];
  char word[]="book";
  FILE *file_handle = fopen ("wordlist.txt", "r");

  for (i =0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
    lines[i] = (char*)malloc (128); /* allocating a memory slot of 128 chars */
    fscanf (file_handle, "%s", lines[i]);
    count[i]=minDistance(word,lines[i]);
    cout<<lines[i]<<" ";
    cout<<count[i]<<endl;
    }

  for (i =0; i < 5; ++i)
    free (lines[i]);

}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  lines();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: #1. Use std::string ans std::vector. #2.Realize the world is now a more beautiful place. #3???? #4 profits.

Comment: In most debuggers they initialize the integer variables with zero, so try to initialize that integer array you have.

Comment: there should be nothing called `I'm trying to make a c/c++ program`. These two ___are___ different language and meant to be different.

Comment: @3bdalla Done that. Still the same.

Comment: @FélixCantournet I don't have a good knowledge of vectors. I'll look into it. Thank you. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I understand. But the two languages can be combined. You just need to add the required headers. Rest is pretty much the same. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user3508140 I'm afraid you're wrong. Just having the same _syntax_ does not make two languages ___same___. As I said, they are different, and ___should___ be treated that way.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'll take care of that. Thank you. :)

Comment: @FélixCantournet Using vectors did the trick. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the lines in your code :

```
int **d = new int*[l2 + 1];
for(i=0;i<l1+1;++i)
```

You are allocating memory for `(l2 + 1)` number of `int*` and you are looping `i` from `0 to (l1 + 1)`. So if `l2 < l1`, you are accessing memory you have not allocated.

Also don't mix C++ and C. Either use C or stick with C++. As mentioned in the comments, if you can use C++, use `std::vector` and `std::string` - it will reduce your headache. Also use C++'s IO classes to perform File IO and always close any file you have opened. (i.e. in C, use `fclose(file_ptr)` ).

Comment: Yeah I see where i was wrong. A little study of vectors and I was able to solve the problem. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You use l2 as your second index.  It should be your first index and l1 your second index.

```
// the edit distance between an empty string and the prefixes of
// word2
for (i = 0; i < l1 + 1; i++) {
    d[0][i] = i;
}
```